# SELECT with Multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have query with multi condition inside php

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = ".$rid." AND `check_in_date` = ".$check_in_date." AND `check_out_date` = ".$check_out_date);
```

when printing query I want it like this

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = 1 AND `check_in_date` = '2015-10-10' AND `check_out_date` = '2015-10-11'
```

Comment: Where are you printing the query?

Comment: what is stuff to suffering....

Comment: What is the problem? Missing quotes? Add them?

Comment: print in browser to check query

Comment: Not sure what the question is please provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

In query there are missing quotes for date (date should be treated as string (varchar):

```
$rid = '--';
$check_out_date = $check_in_date = ' 2005-12-12 ';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = '".$rid."' ";
    $query .= " AND `check_in_date` = '".$check_in_date."' ";
    $query .= " AND `check_out_date` = '".$check_out_date . "';"; 

    echo $query;
```

SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = ' --' AND `check_in_date` = ' 2005-12-12 ' AND `check_out_date` = ' 2005-12-12 '

Comment: when print query i show this SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = '1' AND `check_in_date` = '2015-10-10' AND `check_out_date` = '2015-10-11'SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `rid` = '1' AND `check_in_date` = '2015-10-10' AND `check_out_date` = '2015-10-11'

Comment: I added ';', so should be fine now